# Scala Monoid Combinator for Options

Tags: scala, monoids

Let's say that I have a Monoid trait as below:

```
trait Monoid[A] {
  def combine(a1: A, a2: A): A
  def identity: A
}
```

Now if I want to write an optionMonoid for this, I could write it like this:

```
val optionMonoid1 = new Monoid[Option[A]] {
  def combine(a1: Option[A], a2: Option[A2]) a1 orElse a2
  def identity = None
}
```

This given the fact that I do not know anything about the inner type in the Option. But what if I want to have the combine operator in such a way that I want to really combine the inner types in the Option?

Comment: If you want to `map` over the values inside the `Option`, you'll need a Functor instance.

Comment: But hang on, wouldn't a Functor instance change my type that is contained inside the Option?

Comment: Even if I have a Functor instance, I still do not know what type my A is so that I could apply the combine operator on my Type A!

Comment: You can already take advantage of the fact `Option` is a Functor and has a `map` function. But what does it really mean to combine two Options? You're combining two containers which may or may not hold a value. What you need is for type `A` to have a Monoid instance so you can internally combine these `A`s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option:

```
trait Semigroup[A] {
  def combine(a1: A, a2: A): A
}

trait Monoid[A] extends Semigroup[A] {
  def identity: A
}

def optionMonoid2[A](implicit sgA: Semigroup[A]) = new Monoid[Option[A]] {
  def combine(a1: Option[A], a2: Option[A2]) = (a1, a2) match {
    case (Some(b1), Some(b2)) => Some(sgA.combine(b1, b2))
    case _ => a1.orElse(a2)
  }
  def identity = None
}
```

It's easy to verify monoid laws hold.

Comment: `def identity = None` How does that hold for the `Some` case?

Comment: So here the comine operator works for whatever Semigroup instance that is visible in the scope!°

Comment: @sparkr It is as I've commented above. You need the type contained inside the box (`A`) to have monoidal properties as well.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the helkp!

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Because for all `x: A`, `optionMonoid2.combine(Some(x), None) == Some(x).orElse(None) == Some(x)` and `optionMonoid2.combine(None, Some(x)) == None.orElse(Some(x)) == Some(x)`.